# Skewness calculator using one pass algorithm. Code speed up needed

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, statistics

Helllo,

I am using a one pass algorithm to calculate skewness. My code (in MATLAB) is as follows:

```
n = 10000000;
timeseries = randi(1000, 1, n);

tic
sk = skewness_onepass(timeseries);
toc

function skewness = skewness_onepass(x)
    
    N = length(x);
    M1 = 0;
    M2 = 0;
    M3 = 0;

    % Algorithm taken from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Higher-order_statistics
    for n = 1: N
        delta = x(n) - M1;
        M1 = M1 + delta / n;
        M3 = M3 + delta * delta * delta * (n - 1) * (n - 2) / (n * n) - 3 * delta * M2 / n;
        M2 = M2 + delta * delta * (n - 1) / n;
    end
    
    std_dev = sqrt(M2 / N);

    % Calculate skewness
    skewness = (M3 / N) / (std_dev * std_dev * std_dev);
    
end
```

**My Concern**:

Is there anything I can do to speed up this code? My application is really time critical and I want to evaluate skewness as fast as possible.

Reading online seems to suggest that extending MATLAB using **C++** (I know bit of C but not C++) could help, but I have no clue about this. If this is indeed something that can help, please provide code/snippet on how to execute this.

I also have other functions like this and I am hoping that lessons learnt on this can be used on those as well.

Thanks!

Comment: You could add another variable delta2 = delta*delta since you use it in a couple of places which would save one multiplication in the inner loop. Similarly, you calculate (n-1)/n in a couple of places. Storing the result in another variable might introduce more rounding errors though. You could try to parallelise it with multithreading or SIMD in c or c++ but it looks non-trivial.

Comment: What's your performance target for what data size/type?

Comment: @SimonGoater I don't have a specific target but the faster the better. I have developed a technique which requires calculating moving window skewness. The faster this is the more elaborate my main technique can be. If this is slow, then I have to compromise on my main computations.

Comment: Do the 'windows' overlap the data at all? I'm not sure I understood what you meant but if you're calculating the skewness of an interval of indexes, say [i1, i2], then you need to calculate it again for indexes [i1+1, i2+1], then you would be doing a lot more work than needed. I suggest you describe what you're trying to do in its entirety. By the way, I manually translated your function to c and I get around 22 cycles per element for 1,000,000+ elements (Core i5). Is that not fast enough? What do you get in Matlab?

Comment: @SimonGoater No, I am not using this to calculate skewness for a moving window over the data. For that the code will have to be altered to avoid the issue of recalculation as you have pointed out. Also, can you explain what you mean by 22 cycles per element for 1,000,000 elements? What do you mean by cycles?

Comment: CPU cycles. 3GHz CPU 3,000,000,000 cycles per second.